# Count and RANK in msyql , PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I need help with my query, i have a trackdb table  that i need to get total count then rank them per user.

``` trackdb
----------``
ID  task   task2   task3   task4   task5   task6   User   Date
1   Clean  Repair                                  Emp1   1/1/2019
2   Repair                                         Emp2   1/2/2019
3   Clean                                          Emp1   1/5/2019
4   Repair                                         Emp3   1/6/2019
5   Clean                                          Emp1   1/10/2019 ```

I want to get the total task done for each User per month then Rank them

> SELECT User,COUNT(CASE WHEN (task='Clean' OR task='Repair')  THEN 1 END )  AS totaltask ,COUNT(CASE WHEN (task2='Clean' OR task3='Repair')  THEN 1 END )  AS totaltask1 ,COUNT(CASE WHEN (task3='Clean' OR task3='Repair')  THEN 1 END )  AS totaltask ,COUNT(CASE WHEN (task4='Clean' OR task4='Repair')  THEN 1 END )  AS totaltask ,COUNT(CASE WHEN (task5='Clean' OR task5='Repair')  THEN 1 END )  AS totaltask ,COUNT(CASE WHEN (task6='Clean' OR task6='Repair')  THEN 1 END )  AS totaltask , FROM trackdb WHERE YEAR(date_received)='$period'  AND User='$empname' AND MONTH(date_received)='$month'

```
$resultprod = mysqli_query($database,$queryprod);  
$rowprod = mysqli_fetch_array($resultprod);
$totprod = $rowprod['totaltask'] + $rowprod['totaltask1'] + $rowprod['totaltask2'] + $rowprod['totaltask3'] + $rowprod['totaltask4'] + $rowprod['totaltask5'];
```

I was able to get the total task of Emp1 per month per Year with the above query however i needed to get also the rank of Emp1 if compared with the other Employee.

Hope someone can help, Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem a few months ago. Use dynamic pivot with group_concat like this.

```
SET @sql_dynamic = (
    SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT
            CONCAT(
                'SUM( IF(MONTH(trx_date) = '
                , MONTH(trx_date)
                , ', amount,0) ) AS mo_'
                , MONTH(trx_date)
            )
        )
    FROM sales_table
);

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT name, ', 
              @sql_dynamic, ' 
           FROM sales_table
           GROUP BY name WITH ROLLUP'
       );

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Result:

+---------+------+------+------+
| name    | mo_1 | mo_2 | mo_3 |
+---------+------+------+------+
| Alfa    |  375 |  815 |  375 |
| Bravo   |  310 |  525 |  825 |
| Charlie |  850 |  300 |  725 |
| Delta   |    0 | 1000 |  370 |
| NULL    | 1535 | 2640 | 2295 |
+---------+------+------+------+